# Input redirection problem while using execvp?

Tags: c, fork, redirect

I have Implemented a simple program which simulates `$ls -l | wc -c` command execution using simple pipes and execvp calls.

Now After redirecting stdin and stdout ,when executes the program , shell prompt  disappears and it waits for the enter key to be pressed.

Any way of solving this issue . Plz criticize my code also..

Thanks

```
 /* Create pipe */
  ret_val=pipe(pipe_fd);
  /*Error check */
   if(ERROR==ret_val)
   {
    perror("Pipe creation error \n");
    _exit(FAILURE);
   }

/*Fork First Child */
pid_one = fork() ;

if( 0 == pid_one ) /*child process block */
{


    /* First sub process */
    /*printf("First sub process is %d \n",getpid());*/

    /* redirect stdout to pipe's write end  for sub process one*/
    dup2(pipe_fd[1],1);


    /*close pipe read end */
    close(pipe_fd[0]);

    execvp(cmd_one_tokens[0],cmd_one_tokens);   

    /* if execvp returns then if must have failed */
    printf("Unknown Command \n ");
    //exit(10);
}
else /*main process block */
{
    /*printf(" Main  process is %d \n",getpid());*/

    /*Wait for first sub process to finish */
    //wait(&status);

    /*printf("Exit status of first child is %d \n ", WEXITSTATUS(status) );*/

    /*Fork second subprocess */
    pid_two = fork();

    if( 0 == pid_two ) /*second child process block */
    {
        /* redirect stdin  to pipe's read end  for sub process two */
        dup2(pipe_fd[0],0);

    //  close(0);       /* close normal stdin */
        //  dup(pipe_fd[0]);   /* make stdib same as pfds[0] */


        /*close pipe write end */
        close(pipe_fd[1]);

        /* Second  sub process */
        /*printf("Second sub process is %d \n",getpid()); */

        execvp(cmd_two_tokens[0] , cmd_two_tokens); 
        /* if execvp returns then if must have failed */
        printf("Unknown Command \n ");

    }
    else        /*main process block */
    {
        /* printf(" Main  process is %d \n",getpid()); */
        status=-1; /*reset status */

        /*Waiting for the second sub process to finish in No hang fashion */
            waitpid ( -1 , &status ,WNOHANG);
        /*printf("Exit status of second  child is %d \n ", WEXITSTATUS(status) ); */

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close the pipe file descriptors in the main process, after the second is forked.  Until you have closed them, the child process (`wc`) will wait for input on the pipe which the main process still has open.  You must be very careful to close all the unneeded ends of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not do what you describe you want to do:

You create a pipe, fork a new process, redirect it's stdout to the pipe and make it execute some program (so far so good), then in the parent process you wait for your child to finish and only then fork second process, redirect it's stdin to the pipe other end and make it execute another program.

This is not what "ls | wc" does - in the shell they are running concurrently. Remove the first wait().

Comment: Ok, I have changed it . Could you provide any suggestion for that Prompt issue....

Comment: Just a guess, but I would try to fflush(NULL) at the end of the program.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> pid_one = fork() ;
> if( 0 == pid_one ) /*child process block */
> ```

You're not checking `fork(2)` for an error return, which is a very real possibility. (The user could be bumping up against their `RLIMIT_NPROC` limit, `kernel.threads-max`, run out of memory for holding task structures, etc.)

More idiomatic use of `fork(2)` looks like this:

```
if(-1 == (pid = fork()) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1); /* or return -1 or similar */
} else if (0 == pid) {
    /* executing as child */
} else {
    /* parent, pid is child */
}
```

> ```
> execvp(cmd_two_tokens[0] , cmd_two_tokens); 
> /* if execvp returns then if must have failed */
> printf("Unknown Command \n ");
> ```

Note that there are *many* reasons why `execvp(3)` can fail; simply printing "Unknown Command" may leave your users *very* confused in the future. It'd be better to call `perror("execvp");` and give your users a chance to discover the *real* reason why their `execvp(3)` call failed.

> ```
>  waitpid ( -1 , &status ,WNOHANG);
> ```

Use of `WNOHANG` here might be dangerous; if the system is running "just right", your parent might get to this code before the child has even had a chance to begin executing. Because you've asked for it to return immediately if no child has exited, the child will probably be turned into a zombie when it finally does exit -- your code doesn't take the opportunity to wait for the child again.

I'm not sure what the best solution is: if you use `SA_NOCLDWAIT` to `sigaction(2)` to avoid creating zombies completely, you won't have an opportunity to ever collect the child's exit status. Installing a `SIGCHLD` signal handler might interfere with the rest of the process; your clients might have reason to set it themselves. Using a blocking `waitpid(2)` might stall processing elsewhere. And using a non-blocking `waitpid(2)` means you still have to collect the child's status *sometime*, possibly through polling. (But you can't use `-1` for the `pid` in that case, as you might accidentally reap another child process.)