# Where should I use wait and waitpid in this code?

Tags: c, fork, pipe, execvp

I have written a program which simulates '$ls -l | wc -c ' like commands using pipes.
Now I am not able to find out where should I use wait or waitpid in this code.

Also where should I close pipes ?
Please review my code and suggest .

```
int main (   int argc , char *argv[] )
{

char *cmd_one_tokens[MAX];  /* Array of pointer to hold tokens of first command */
char *cmd_two_tokens[MAX];  /* Array of pointer to hold tokens of second command */

pid_t pid_one = -1 , /* variable to hold process id of first sub process */
      pid_two = -1 ; /* variable to hold process id of second sub process */
int status    = -1 ; /* variable to read the status of the child process */
int pipe_fd[2] = {-1,-1}; /* Array to hold descriptors returned by pipe sys call */
int ret_val    =-1 ; /* variable to hold return values by system calls */

/*Validate Number of command line arguments */
if(3 != argc)
{
    printf("Provide Appropriate Arguments  \n <lab3> < \"arg1\" > < \"arg2\" > \n");
    _exit(FAILURE);

}
/*Parse first command and get the tokens */
parse_command(argv[1],cmd_one_tokens);
/*Parse second command and get the tokens */
parse_command(argv[2],cmd_two_tokens);


/* Create pipe */
ret_val=pipe(pipe_fd);
/*Error check */
if(ERROR==ret_val)
{
    perror("Pipe creation error \n");
    _exit(FAILURE);
}
/*Fork First Child */
pid_one = fork() ;
//Error check
if( 0 == pid_one ) /*child process block */
{

    /* redirect stdout to pipe's write end  for sub process one*/
    dup2(pipe_fd[1],1);

    /*close pipe read end */
    close(pipe_fd[0]);

    execvp(cmd_one_tokens[0],cmd_one_tokens);   

    /* if execvp returns then if must have failed */
    //Error check 

}
else /*main process block */
{

    /*Wait for first sub process to finish */
    waitpid ( pid_two , &status ,0); // <-------changes

    /*Fork second subprocess */
    pid_two = fork();
            //Error check
    if( 0 == pid_two ) /*second child process block */
    {
        /* redirect stdin  to pipe's read end  for sub process two */
        dup2(pipe_fd[0],0);

        /*close pipe write end */
        close(pipe_fd[1]);

        execvp(cmd_two_tokens[0] , cmd_two_tokens); 
        /* if execvp returns then if must have failed */
        //Error check 

    }
    else        /*main process block */
    {
        status=-1; /*reset status */

        /*Waiting for the second sub process to finish in No hang fashion */
             waitpid ( pid_two , &status ,0);  // <-------changes

    }
}
return(SUCCESS);        

}/*End of main */
```

Comment: I really wish you had taken [my advice from last time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610184/input-redirection-problem-while-using-execvp/5610320#5610320) and checked the return values from `fork(2)` for errors before posting again.

Comment: Yeah I have done it. I tried to properly put waits and sometimes its works fine and some time it gives pipe_w on ps ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a while loop in the parent process (after the children are spawned) calling `wait` continuously until both children terminate:

```
while (wait(&status) != -1);
```

In your particular situation you can avoid `waitpid`.

Comment: I used wait for both sub process , but it hangs. When I saw it using ps it gives  pipe_w ...........

Comment: Hanging is what `wait` does :-) Could you be more specific?

Comment: Maybe some of the children doesn't terminate then?

Comment: Ok, now I am going to edit the code and show you what exactly I have written..........

Comment: This answer is a nice hint! Worked for me, too.